# How do I use a column in a single-row tables as a scalar?

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose I have a table `tab1` with only *one* row and bigger tables `big1` and `big2`.
How do I use a column in `tab1` (which contains a single number) as a scalar, in, e.g.,

```
select a.foo * tab1.bar - b.quux
from big1 a join big2 b by big1.id = big2.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do another join. It's only one row, so it's not expensive:

```
select a.foo * tab1.bar - b.quux
from big1 a join big2 b by big1.id = big2.id join tab1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of overkill, but you can use the `distributed_map` UDF in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) and create a map with only one key

```
insert overwrite directory 'mytab1'
select bar, 'value' from tab1;

add file mytab1;

select a.foo * array_index( map_keys( distributed_map( 'mytab1' ) ),0 ) - b.quux
from big1 a join big2 b on ( big1.id = big2.id )
```